# Change CSS properties on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, onclick

I am trying to change the CSS of one element on click of another element. I've searched a lot but nothing works perfectly. Currently I am using the below code, but it doesn't work. Can anyone tell me what I missed?

```
<div id="foo">hello world!</div>
<img src="zoom.png" onclick="myFunction()" />
```

```js
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById('foo').style.cssText = 'background-color: red; color: white; font-size: 44px';
}
```

Comment: Why are you not just setting a new class and have the styles in a stylesheet?

Comment: What browser are you testing it in? Are there errors in the JS console?

Comment: Use jQuery :), it is easier

Comment: @epascarello i am trying it on fiddle just to run this simple script

Comment: @Bandpay i am thinking too.. can you guide me any link please

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Firstly, using `on*` attributes to add event handlers is a very outdated way of achieving what you want. As you've tagged your question with jQuery, here's a jQuery implementation:

```
<div id="foo">hello world!</div>
<img src="zoom.png" id="image" />
```

```js
$('#image').click(function() {
    $('#foo').css({
        'background-color': 'red',
        'color': 'white',
        'font-size': '44px'
    });
});
```

A more efficient method is to put those styles into a class, and then add that class onclick, like this:

```js
$('#image').click(function() {
  $('#foo').addClass('myClass');
});
```

```css
.myClass {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  font-size: 44px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="foo">hello world!</div>
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/9zbkKVz.png?1" id="image" />
```

Here's a plain Javascript implementation of the above for those who require it:

```js
document.querySelector('#image').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.querySelector('#foo').classList.add('myClass');
});
```

```css
.myClass {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  font-size: 44px;
}
```

```html
<div id="foo">hello world!</div>
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/9zbkKVz.png?1" id="image" />
```

Comment: This answer uses jQuery, but the question was using plain Javascript.  That's probably why it's also confusing some people who try to use it.

Comment: @orrd The OP tagged jQuery in the question, and I stated that this is a jQuery implementation of a solution. Who exactly has been confused by it? I see no comments asking for any clarification?

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question of why their code doesn't work.

Comment: @RobG That's because there isn't enough information in the OP to diagnose a problem. The example the OP gives works absolutely fine (https://jsfiddle.net/k9rL517m/). My first assumption is that the `myFunction()` is not declared in scope of the `onclick` event attribute, ie. not within the `window`, but that would only be an assumption

Comment: A javascript code can be better than jquery

Answer (score 20):

Try this:

**CSS**

```
.style1{
    background-color:red;
    color:white;
    font-size:44px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="foo">hello world!</div>
<img src="zoom.png" onclick="myFunction()" />
```

**Javascript**

```
function myFunction()
{
    document.getElementById('foo').setAttribute("class", "style1");
}
```

Answer (score 9):

```
    <script>
        function change_css(){
            document.getElementById('result').style.cssText = 'padding:20px; background-color:#b2b2ff; color:#0c0800; border:1px solid #0c0800; font-size:22px;';
        }
    </script>

</head>

<body>
    <center>
        <div id="error"></div>
        <center>
            <div id="result"><h2> Javascript Example On click Change Css style</h2></div>
            <button onclick="change_css();">Check</button><br />
        </center>
    </center>
</body>
```

Comment: This is best and most simple answer

Answer (score 2):

In your code you aren't using jquery, so, if you want to use it, yo need something like...

```
$('#foo').css({'background-color' : 'red', 'color' : 'white', 'font-size' : '44px'});
```

http://api.jquery.com/css/

Other way, if you are not using jquery, you need to do ...

```
document.getElementById('foo').style = 'background-color: red; color: white; font-size: 44px';
```

Answer (score 1):

With jquery you can do it like:

```
$('img').click(function(){
    $('#foo').css('background-color', 'red').css('color', 'white');
});
```

this applies for all `img` tags you should set an `id` attribute for it like `image` and then:

```
$('#image').click(function(){
    $('#foo').css('background-color', 'red').css('color', 'white');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="foo">hello world!</div>
<img src="zoom.png" id="click_me" />
```

JS

```
$('#click_me').click(function(){
  $('#foo').css({
    'background-color':'red',
    'color':'white',
    'font-size':'44px'
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#foo').css({backgroundColor:'red', color:'white',fontSize:'44px'});
```

Answer (score 0):

This code seems to work fine (see this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mEE69/)). Is your javascript defined *before* your body?
When the browser reads `onclick="myFunction()"` it has to know what `myFunction` is.

Answer (score 0):

Man, see I don't know about JavaScript. But using `:active` css property, you can achieve the css properties you want on click!