# Load HTML Thank You on Contact Form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, contacts

Instead of "Message Sent" alert, I would like to load hidden HTML content. Once the user fills out the required fields, through HTML, a Thank You message/image will appear along with an exclusive Pay Now button. Here's the link http://thebrlab.com/razor-chic-of-atlanta/sign-up.php

Comment: Have you tried anything specific to get it to work?

Comment: just hide the form div after success and put the thank you message and button in Place of Welcome Sent!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either do this with javascript inserting the div, set the display to none (`display:none`), then when the button is clicked, use javascript to change the attribute to `display:block`.

Without more information, I can't give you a better answer.

Comment: That sounds like it will do the trick. I uploaded the div I want to load once the form is submitted. My question is: What javascript coding can I use to achieve this? Here's the link again http://thebrlab.com/razor-chic-of-atlanta/sign-up.php

Comment: Without the html, I can't give you the code. But you would use `click` and then set the css to `display:block.` You could do this in less than 10 lines of code, probably closer to 5... It's pretty simple, just look up how to change css on button click with javascript

Comment: Is this a good example? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14319274/change-css-on-click

Comment: Yeah, that is one way to do it.

Comment: Ok I tried to apply this method, it's not working for me. Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong? http://thebrlab.com/razor-chic-of-atlanta/sign-up.php

Comment: No, I can't. I can't see the code. If you want help wit your code, you need to post all the code you are using so we can see what is going on. I would post your code in a new question and get help that way, but you have to post the code you are using