# How to change the colour of a div element when clicked?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a this html page, Whenever the element with class name FreeSeat is clicked I want to change the colour of that div element.Below is my html page

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>
   QuickBus
  </title>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="Seat.css">
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="Bus">
   <div class="Row">
    <div class="FreeSeat"  ></div>
    <div class="FreeSeat"  ></div>
    <div class="ResSeat"  ></div>
    <div class="ResSeat"  ></div>
    <div class="ResSeat"  ></div>
   </div>
  </div>
 <body>
</html>
```

It will be very helpful if anyone can help me out with this .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change CSS properties on click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14319274/change-css-properties-on-click) and a host of others found by searching SO.

Answer (score 3):

Considering that you want to use pure JS and not any library, you'd have to manually add event listeners to your classes.
And it has been solved for a [similar problem here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19655189/javascript-click-event-listener-on-class)

```
var freeclass = document.getElementsByClassName("FreeSeat");
var myFunction_Free = function() {
    this.style.color = "blue";
}
for(var i=0;i<freeclass.length;i++){
    freeclass[i].addEventListener('click', myFunction_Free, false);
}
```

But for your case, here's a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chechs/qmhs4b3s/)

Answer (score 2):

JQuery is amazing for these sorts of things.

Say you have a div with id 'box1'

`<div id='box1'></div>`

Style it with css

```
#box1 {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:white;
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

Using JQuery, you can make this call:

```
$( "#box1" ).click(function() {
  $('#box1').css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

And now whenever your `div` is clicked, the colour will change, you can customise this however much you like.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/9meL3mnk/) is a JSFiddle demo.

Also, since you didn't specify exactly what you want to change the colour *of*, in my example jquery, it is telling the browser that when a `div` with an id of `box1`is clicked, change the `background-color` of the `div` with an id of `box1`, you can change anything though.

If you have a `<p>` tag you can change that too when the div is clicked, hope this helped!

Comment: You don't need jQuery to do this and it's just as easy in plain javascript.

Comment: It might very well be, but this is just an example using jQuery, but I do prefer it over JS. Could you please show me an example using plain JS? @Rob

Comment: If you want that, you have to start your own question. Also, jQuery IS javascript. Better yet, just search SO or Google for an example.

Comment: OP didn't specifically for pure javascript, so I assumed this might help him, I'll take a look later! :)

Comment: My point is, it's not necessary to load an entire library just to do something as simple as changing the color of an element.

Comment: You're right, but in doing so, it makes other things much simpler to do.

Comment: You presume he wants to do "other things" and those other things are more difficult in plain javascript. I've never found that to be the case.

Comment: And you presume he doesn't, I am sure there is more to his project than changing the colour of a div, either way, this is just an example and it is up to OP whether or not he wants to use it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following method to change the background color of an element by class:

```
const free_seat = document.getElementsByClassName('FreeSeat');
free_seat[0].style.backgroundColor = '#ff0';
```

Each element can be referenced by its index:

```
free_seat[0] // first div
free_seat[1] // second div
```

Therefore, we can create a function that will be called whenever the [`click`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/click) event is delivered to the target:

```
const change_color = () => {
  this.style.backgroundColor = '#ff0';
};

for (let i = 0; i < free_seat.length; i++) {
  free_seat[i].addEventListener('click', change_color);
}
```

> **Note:** You can also use `document.querySelectorAll('.FreeSeat')` to obtain a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) of elements of a certain class.

Answer (score 1):

You can use simply the css focus pseudo-class for this:

```
#foo:focus {
    background-color:red;
}

<div id="foo" tabindex="1">hello world!</div>
```

Dont forget to set the tabindex.