# How do i give a hyperlink an id when it is clicked to initiate some css?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, onclick

I have a navigation bar that has a few links that do not link to pages, but pass data through GET, depending on which data is displayed from my database.

```
<a href="./welcome.php?cat=1" class="primary_cat" id="selected">NEW</a>
```

The id 'selected' styles the navigation bar link to display as been currently selected.
How do i move this id attribute between these links for the css to show them as currently selected?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change CSS properties on click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14319274/change-css-properties-on-click)

Comment: do you realize PHP runs BEFORE javascript? View the page source and look at what is in the onclick attribute.

Comment: The PHP is executed on server-side, the onclick will be executed on user-side. You'll have to put that in mind. Plus you are using double quotes inside other double quotes without escaping them which is wrong!

Comment: yeah, it was silly of me to do that. I have edited the problem, and i really want a solution.

Comment: Probably better to use a class instead of id, since id's should be unique. The way to add the click event is shown in the link SzymonM posted. But as stated above, might as well change it serverside, since you'll load a new page anyway, unless the link you want to style isn't the one shown in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Remove id, use class like this:

```
<a href="./welcome.php?cat=1" class="primary_cat selected">NEW</a>
```

Import jquery

Add in your JS file:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('a').click(function(){
        $('a').removeClass("selected");
        $(this).addClass("selected");
      });
    });
```

In css file:

```
.selected {
  color: pink;
}
```