# input-group-addon change color with onclick

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick, onclicklistener

I am trying to change the input-group-addon background-color with an onclick javascript function. It seems i can not get this working.

Anyone has an idea?

color = the name of the color (for example 'red').

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeColor(color, id) {
        document.getElementById('onColor').innerHTML = color;
    }
</script>
```

Below background-color is set to red.  **How can I get the text echo'ed from the function changeColor instead of the text red? So I can put any color into it I want, and the color changes on the clicked radio button.**

```
 <div class="input-group" style="width:100%">
                        <span class="input-group-addon" style="background-color:red"></span>
                        <input id="bet" type="number" class="form-control" name="bet" placeholder="Lira">
                    </div>
```

**EDIT:**
Seems style change with javascript is the answer (not innerHTML).
See: [Change CSS properties on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14319274/change-css-properties-on-click)

Comment: you need to change the style not innerHTML

Comment: Where's your `document.getElementById('onColor')` Element?  What you're looking for is `Element.style.backgroundColor = color;`

Comment: I dont know. I am not very good with javascript. I am just trying some things out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14319274/change-css-properties-on-click Would this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**`document.getElementById(id).style`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style) to change element's **css** , not [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML).

```html
<div class="input-group" style="width:100%">
  <span id="input-addon" class="input-group-addon"> Span </span>
  <input id="bet" type="number" class="form-control" name="bet" placeholder="Lira">
</div>


<button onclick="changeColor('red', 'input-addon')">Change Color</button>
  


<script type="text/javascript">
  function changeColor(color, id) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.color = color;
  }
</script>
```