# Add colour frame to image onClick

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want, when something happens (Ex: Click a button), that my image creates a frame around. Something like this:

[Image before, without the frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwBrV.jpg)

[Image after click, with the frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pU4hu.jpg)

Can I do that with CSS?

I don't want to have two links nor two images. I want that "transformation" happens to the original image.

**EDIT:** I know I don't have any code, but that's because I don't have any function or idea from CSS functions. So you don't need to write code, only to tell me what to use. Hope you understand

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14319274/change-css-properties-on-click I would try the second answer

Comment: But I only want to change the border of the image, can I do that? According with the second answer, I will change the background-color of all image no? And thanks a lot for the answer @Katie.Sun !

Comment: you will have to change the selector and what css attribute is changed

Comment: Thanks! I already understand how to do it. I have the border attribute in html and css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use javascript `onClick` event handler and css `border` property.

Your html image and button tag.

```
<img src='yourimage.jpg' id='myimg'>
<button onclick="add_frame()">add frame</button>
```

The javascript

```
function add_frame(){

document.getElementById('myimg').style.border = "2px solid red";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using jquery.

Add a class to any image that you want to be able to add a border to (`.border-on-click`), this should include a transparent border within it's CSS (if you don't do this, your elements will move around the page when the border is toggled and takes up extra space).

In the example below you can toggle the border on and off with a click.

It acts upon the image you clicked only.

Let me know if this wasn't what you wanted.

```js
$(".border-on-click").click( function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("framed");
});
```

```css
img.border-on-click {
  border: 4px solid transparent;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

img.border-on-click.framed {
  border: 4px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img class="border-on-click" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
```

Comment: I wasn't looking for a jquery solution, but that will help me too. Because I want to use a "draggable" function, instead of "on click". Thanks. That will work for me.