# How to change css property when you click on button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, click

I want when i click in each one of them to pop the span element with class color but only for that button.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I only achieved when i click on one of them to change the visibility to visible on all elements with class colors.

my Code : https://jsbin.com/govowakasa/edit?js

```
document.getElementById("btn-apple").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  showColor()
});

function showColor() {
  const colors = document.getElementsByClassName("color");
  for (let i=0; i<colors.length; i++) {
    colors[i].style.visibility = 'visible';
}};
```

Comment: show your html (and maybe css) as well; the function of classname `color` is ambiguous

Comment: You can pass the index of the span as parameter to showColor function

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14319274/change-css-properties-on-click

Comment: https://jsbin.com/govowakasa/edit?js 

My code

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You **can not** use the same `ID` for more than 1 element.
I replaced the IDs of buttons with a new class name `fruit-btn`.
Then I made an array in JS of both buttons and color spans.
Then I looped through each button to add an `EventListener`.
In the event I added another loop that hides every color span and then makes the `i` span visible. There is no need for a function.

```js
const fruit_btn = document.getElementsByClassName("fruit-btn");
const color_spans = document.getElementsByClassName("color");

for (let i = 0; i < fruit_btn.length; i++) {
  fruit_btn[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    for (let i = 0; i < fruit_btn.length; i++) {
      color_spans[i].style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
    color_spans[i].style.visibility = "visible";
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 2rem;
}

li {
  margin: 20px;
  list-style: none;
}

button i {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 3rem;
}

.color {
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: blanchedalmond;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Fruits</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="list.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-0S+nbAYis87iX26mmj/+fWt1MmaKCv80H+Mbo+Ne7ES4I6rxswpfnC6PxmLiw33Ywj2ghbtTw0FkLbMWqh4F7Q==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
  />
</head>

<body>
  <p>
    FRUITS
  </p>
  <ul>
    <li class="items">
      <button class="fruit-btn"><i class="fas fa-apple-alt"></i></button>
      <span class="color">red and yellow</span>
    </li>
    <li class="items">
      <button class="fruit-btn"><i class="fas fa-carrot"></i></button>
      <span class="color">orange</span>
    </li>
    <li class="items">
      <button class="fruit-btn"><i class="fas fa-lemon"></i></button>
      <span class="color">yellow</span>
    </li>
    <li class="items">
      <button class="fruit-btn"><i class="fas fa-pepper-hot"></i></button>
      <span class="color">red and green</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <script src="/week-4/index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I would suggest to add/remove a Class instead of adding/removing directly CSS styling.

Comment: Thanks, yeah i totally know that and this is my old jsfidle that i sent after that i realised that and i changed 4 different ids (btn-apple, btn-carrot, btn-lemon, btn-pepper) and i did this for all of them 
document.getElementById("btn-apple").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  showColor()
});
and then the function but still couldn't get it for all. 
Another loop in the event is the answer.

Thanks a LOT

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add this line

```
 fruits[i].style.backgroundColor = 'red'
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).